# How basically Shards and replicas distribute itself

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, elk

I am trying to install Single Cluster - multi nodes environment of Elastic search Environment on my local machine. Got confused over concept of Shards and replicas

Case 1 ) in below pic : emp index  no of shards =1 and no of replica =1 , that seems fine as primary node dont contains replica and number of shards should be 1 so one of the another node is allocated which becomes its shard as well as replica

Case 2) In case 2 for employee index - i increased no of shards =2  and no of replica =2 - >

what that below head plugin suggesting

1) do number of shard we set is present in each of the node - e.g. 2 in case of employee - 2 shards are present on each node and out of them 2 are replica ?? why in case of emp its not present in node-2

2) Is shards are not mandatory to be present on master node like shown in case of emp - node 2 dont contains any shards

I know there is concept of unllocated replicas but that should be when my nodes are less than my size of replice .

Any pointer will be helpful.

[image: la]

Comment: Side note: I always follow this **Rule of thumb - "(Number of Replicas =  Number of Nodes - 1)".** So you if you have 2 nodes, then (2-1). only 1 replica. For 1 node only, you dont need replicas - replicas are a backup in case if one of the nodes go down - so its sensless to have a replica on the same node.

Answer (score 0):

seems like I got the answer, as per the article 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/_basic_concepts.html

By default, each index in Elasticsearch is allocated 5 primary shards and 1 replica which means that if you have at least two nodes in your cluster, your index will have 5 primary shards and another 5 replica shards (1 complete replica) for a total of 10 shards per index.

so in my case - when No of shard/no of replica set to 1

Shard -1 and 1 replica - total of 2 shards

when No of shard/no of replica set to 2

No of shards  2 - 
No of replica - 4 ( as each shard has 2 replica) - I was confused here and thought total of 2 replica is created

checked for

No of shard/no of the replica set to 3

and total of 12 shards are generated by my logic.

Please correct me if i am wrong .